# How can I determine which version of Python introduced a particular module to the std lib?

Tags: python, history

Is there a single timeline-style resource available showing the history of the modules available in different versions of Python?

I'd like to, for instance, easily determine which version of Python introduced the `pipes` module, without needing to perform a binary search by installing different Python versions until I find a version that doesn't have it followed immediately by one that does.

Comment: Have you tried doing a binary search of http://docs.python.org/?  It has documentation on many historical versions of Python.

Comment: @Kevin Nope, I had somehow gotten the idea into my head that `python.org` doesn't maintain documentation for old versions. (I think I was confusing this with the C++ standard; it turns out it's very difficult to find old versions of the standard for free online. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26025026/1858225) So that would have worked, though now that I'm exploring it a bit it appears that the layout for the documentation has changed quite a bit over the years, which makes it slightly less convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`pipes` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html) is pretty old. Most standard library modules that have been introduced in the last decade or so state when they were introduced on the module documentation page. For example, the [`sysconfig` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sysconfig.html) was introduced in version 2.7.

Shameless plug: I have written a script called [`pyqver` (on Github)](https://github.com/ghewgill/pyqver) that attempts to identify the minimum version of Python required to run a particular script. In the source, there is a table of modules and functions along with the version of Python where they were introduced. I see that I hadn't even included the `pipes` module because it was so old.

To answer your specific question, it appears that the [`pipes` module was first documented in Python 1.5.2p1](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p1/lib/module-pipes.html), released in July 1999. I found this by clicking through the links at on https://www.python.org/doc/versions/.

However, the `pipes.py` source file is considerably older than that. The first version appeared in October 1992 as can be seen in [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5d437486413f4c758b9a51855fc9c5e77cf6bac4), found from the file history at https://github.com/python/cpython/commits/master/Lib/pipes.py.

Comment: So, to answer the actual, general question: “Tough luck, you need to manually trawl through the docs for each version or through the git log and look whether the module in question is included. See also this script which does the search for you, for some recent-ish Python versions”. I'm a bit surprised Python doesn't have a more convenient mechanism, since Perl ships with the `corelist` tool that does exactly this.

Comment: @amon Sure, but `pyqver` still looks like a pretty awesome resource (thanks GregHewgill!). For most practical purposes, it's probably not even worth knowing which version of Python a module was included in if it was included prior to the introduction of Python 2. That said, an official `corelist`-type thing *would* be nice.